# Devise - emails not being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to implement the auto-lock feature of devise. My app is still in development. I inputted an incorrect password to activate the auto-lock and that works fine but I'm having trouble setting up email to unlock an account.

In config/environments/development.rb I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb I have

```
config.mailer_sender = 'sender@mail.com'
config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
```

and then further down in that same file:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
   config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
   config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
   config.unlock_strategy = :email

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
   config.maximum_attempts = 5

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
   config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
   config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
```

According to my server logs the email has been sent. I see the following:

```
Sent mail to receiver@mail.com (48.3ms)
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 11:25:41 +0100
From: sender@mail.com
Reply-To: sender@mail.com
To: receiver@mail.com
Message-ID: <533be5a583e8d_9b624e20d76904fc@ubuntuSheeka.mail>
Subject: Unlock Instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello receiver@mail.com!</p>

<p>Your account has been locked due to an excessive number of unsuccessful sign in attempts.</p>

<p>Click the link below to unlock your account:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/unlock?unlock_token=yQS9XYp4twxGr1TXMywx">Unlock my account</a></p>
```

The problem is that I'm not seeing the mail in my inbox. Any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you would not have set up email configuration properly:

Just Create a file `email.rb` inside '`config/initializers/`' folder and put the below contents:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method=:smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => "587",
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "<your email username>",
  :password => "<your email passowrd>",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true 
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true 
ActionMailer::Base.default :charset => "utf-8"
ActionMailer::Base.default :content_type => "text/html"
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Sorry, no it didn't. I'm getting a devise error: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::UnlocksController#create        534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required

Comment: Hey, just put your email and password in email.rb. Have you replaced that? Replace <your email username> with your original gmail username and <your email passowrd> with the password for the email account. Then restart server.

Comment: Yes, I put in my email details.

Comment: I tried a different email account and it's working. Thank you so much! Any ideas why I needed to add this? Can I configure devise itself with this information?

Comment: Hope you can accept the answer If it really helped you.

Comment: This is the configuration for ActionMailer to use smtp settings for delivering emails. We can even specify it in environment.rb/production.rb. Please refer http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` occurs due to invalid credentials OR due to captcha problem, I think the problem is occuring due to captcha. Login to your google account and go to this link to disable the captcha, then no `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` will occur. https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha